# Visual Studio Erroneously Adding Data To Resx File

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have a custom user control called DocumentExplorerControl, which has several properties, one of which is called HistoryList.  If I make any change to any form that contains this control, the build will fail with the following error:

```
Invalid Resx file. Could not load type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[xxxxxx.DocumentManager.IHistoryObject, xxxxxx, Version=4.0.5207.25065, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 which is used in the .RESX file.
```

I can double-click the error and it takes me to the problem in the .resx file:

```
  <data name="documentsList.HistoryList" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64">
    <value>
        AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAMAgAAAJkBQURNU19EZXNrdG9wLCBWZXJzaW9uPTQuMC41MjA3LjI1MDY1
        LCBDdWx0dXJlPW5ldXRyYWwsIFB1YmxpY0tleVRva2VuPW51bGxdXSwgbXNjb3JsaWIsIFZlcnNpb249
        NC4wLjAuMCwgQ3VsdHVyZT1uZXV0cmFsLCBQdWJsaWNLZXlUb2tlbj1iNzdhNWM1NjE5MzRlMDg5DAMA
        AABKQURNU19EZXNrdG9wLCBWZXJzaW9uPTQuMC41MjA3LjI1MDY1LCBDdWx0dXJlPW5ldXRyYWwsIFB1
        YmxpY0tleVRva2VuPW51bGwFAQAAAE5TeXN0ZW0uQ29sbGVjdGlvbnMuR2VuZXJpYy5MaXN0YDFbW0FE
        TVNfRGVza3RvcC5Eb2N1bWVudE1hbmFnZXIuSUhpc3RvcnlPYmplY3QDAAAABl9pdGVtcwVfc2l6ZQhf
        dmVyc2lvbgQAAC1BRE1TX0Rlc2t0b3AuRG9jdW1lbnRNYW5hZ2VyLklIaXN0b3J5T2JqZWN0W10DAAAA
        CAgCAAAACQQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAcEAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAABCtBRE1TX0Rlc2t0b3AuRG9jdW1lbnRNYW5h
        Z2VyLklIaXN0b3J5T2JqZWN0AwAAAAs=
    </value>
  </data>
```

This is the only property that is added to the .resx file from this control and if I delete this added data section, the app builds and runs just fine.

This problem is occurring in both Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 on two different machines, and two different users.  The broken .resx file does not prevent anything in the designer from working properly.  Does anyone have an idea of what might be causing this?  I've add the signatures for all the properties of HistoryList below.

HistoryList:

```
Public Property HistoryList As List(Of IHistoryObject)
```

IHistoryObject:

```
Public Interface IHistoryObject
    Property FolderList As List(Of IFolder)
    Property DocumentList As List(Of IDocument)
    Property DefaultHandler As IDocumentHandler
    Property FolderName As String
End Interface
```

IFolder:

```
Public Interface IFolder
    Property FolderName() As String
    Property SubFolders() As List(Of IFolder)
    Property Documents() As List(Of IDocument)
    Property DefaultDocumentHandler() As IDocumentHandler
End Interface
```

IDocument:

```
Public Interface IDocument
    Property DocumentName() As String
    Property DocumentType() As DocumentType
    Property DocumentLocation() As DocumentLocation
    Property ScreenLocation() As ScreenLocation
    Property DocumentIdentifier() As String
    Property Compressed() As Boolean
    Property DocumentHandler() As IDocumentHandler
    Property UsedDocumentId() As Integer
    Property PrivateDocument() As Boolean
    Property SavedDate() As DateTime
    Property KnowledgeLakeDocumentTypeId() As Integer?
    Property KnowledgeLakeDocumentClassId() As Integer?
    Property RequiresFollowUp() As Boolean
    Property Comments() As String
    Property DevelopmentKey() As Integer
    Property Version() As Integer
    Property MonitoringId() As Integer?
    Property FollowUpDate() As Date?
    Property FollowUpUsers As List(Of Integer)
End Interface
```

IDocumentHandler:

```
Public Interface IDocumentHandler
    Sub Open(document As IDocument)
    Sub OpenVersion(sourceTableId As Integer, fileName As String)
    Function Delete(document As IDocument, Optional saveHistory As Boolean = True) As DocumentAddReturnData
    Sub SaveToDisk(document As IDocument, filePath As String, openWhenDone As Boolean)
    Function Add(documentBinary As Byte(), ByRef document As IDocument) As DocumentAddReturnData
    Function Replace(existingDocument As IDocument, newDocument As Byte(), fileName As String) As DocumentAddReturnData
    Function Replace(documentId As Integer, newDocument As Byte()) As DocumentAddReturnData
    Function FileNameExists(fileName As String, Optional developmentKey As Integer = 0, Optional monitoringKey As Integer = 0) As DocumentConstants.FileNameExists
    Function FilePathExists(filePath As String, Optional developmentKey As Integer = 0, Optional monitoringKey As Integer = 0) As DocumentConstants.FileNameExists
    Function AppendFileNumber(fileName As String, Optional developmentKey As Integer = 0, Optional monitoringKey As Integer = 0) As String
End Interface
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Version=4.0.5207.25065

This is what causes the error.  You are letting the [AssemblyVersion] attribute of the assembly that contains the DocumentManager.IHistoryObject implementation type automatically increment.  It would look similar to `<Assembly: AssemblyVersion("4.0.*")>` in the AssemblyInfo.vb source file.  So every time you rebuild, the assembly gets a different version number.  This plays havoc on the serialized data, it still contains the data that was serialized with the original version number.  And is therefore not compatible anymore.  The designer falls over when it tries to deserialize the data in .resx file.

So if you *intend* to keep the .resx file then you'll need to disable this auto-incrementing.  It however sounds like this was accidental and you don't actually want this to happen at all.  Using the DesignMode property test is a workaround but it is not the correct one.  You simple tell the designer to **never** persist the data.  You do so with an attribute:

```
    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)> _
    <Browsable(False)> _
    Public Property History As List(Of IHistoryObject)
```

The [Browsable] attribute also prevents accidents when you edit the property in the Properties window.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  The control and the form are in the same project, so I don't know if that's relevant.  Thanks for the attribute also.  Will switch to that over the design mode test...it didn't feel right to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

While the signature of HistoryList didn't initialize a new collection, and the control's constructor didn't initialize a new collect, a function called from the control's load event did initialize a new collection, so I had to use `If Not Me.DesignMode` to avoid the initialization.