# Adding a list (T) property to a inherited panel class

Tags: vb.net, list, class, properties

I am vey new to programming with classes. I am setting up a new program and want to give it a new, good structure and want to work with classes. But, I am stuck now for two days....I have an object class inherited from a panel. I want to add a list with info to it. IT almost seems to work but the property window in my main form also shows the info collection editor but I get a error which I can not seem to get rid of.. What am I doing wrong.

The error mesage:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       Invalid Resx file. Could not load type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[KRE_Interface.Info, KRE Interface, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 which is used in the .RESX file.  Ensure that the necessary references have been added to your project. Line 915, position 5. KRE Interface   D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\kre\KRESoftware\Alma 1 Interface\20200820 KRE Interface V6\KRE Interface\frmMain.resx    915

My code of the class:

```
 
Public Class RbGroep
    Inherits Panel

    Private m_ItemsInfo As List(Of Info)

    Public Sub New()
        ItemsInfo() = New List(Of Info)
    End Sub

    Property ItemsInfo() As List(Of Info)
        Get
            Return m_ItemsInfo
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of Info))
            m_ItemsInfo = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
<Serializable()>
Public Class Info
    Public Property Order As Integer
    Public Property RbName As String
End Class
```

Comment: The error is issued for a .resx file, which shouldn't contain code.  Maybe there's a problem with how your project is laid out?

Comment: I will start with a complete new fproject and empty form..

Comment: I tried with a complete empty form project, and I got the same result... I inserted a button and the class on the form... How can my project be "Laid out"?

Comment: You're adding a property to a WinForms GUI element - a control.  When this happens, the auto-generated designer classes (including the .resx) will by default try to serialize default values for the property.  If you didn't intend for this, the fastest way to resolve it is to attribute the property to signal that .NET doesn't need to serialize it.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22875607/3791245) for info.

Comment: Since you're new to programming, I would suggest you don't start by inheriting/extending GUI classes - it makes things a lot more complicated.  Might be best to start learning those GUI elements by working with them _as they are_.

Comment: I am not very new to programming, but, being self-tought, I almost never used clases...I have to place a groupbox/panel with some (every time different) radiobuttons on a form.  I wanted to make a panel that I can place several times on all forms. Then, in the properties I wanted to give a ID number and tekst to the panel. Then, in another added property, I wanted to read the value of the panel. Seemed doable to me butnow I am stuck... Any other good solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have it working with the info of Sean Kelly. Thanks a lot. Only: in the class I try to access the list with information, to make some radio bullets.

```
       For i = 0 To amount_of_rb
        Dim newrb As New KRERadiobutton
        newrb.Name = "rb" & i
             newrb.Text = ItemsInfo(i).RbName
              newrb.Tag = itemsinfo(i).Order
        newrb.Tag = i
        newrb.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(40, 20 * i)
        AddHandler newrb.CheckedChanged, AddressOf RadioButton1_CheckedChanged
        Me.Controls.Add(newrb)
    Next
```

The line with the itemsinfo(i) give me errors. Anybody an idea how to adress these bvariables?

Comment: in the meantime I found an error in the  boundary of the for loop.  I did not recognise the out-of-bounds error... However, my resx error is bac kagain when building the form...  I thought I had rebuild it already and it went oke but now it isback again.... it is a bit frustrating.....:)

Answer (score -1):

Add this line to the top of the `.vb` file containing your class:
`Imports System.Collections.Generic`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added this to the class file and even to my mainForm code but it gets grayed out directly as it is not used.... And, it does not fix anything either.... Pitty.... Maybe it needs also a small code change to use this?